# Crashing in a for loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to write to a text file. I can write fine when I don't use my for loop, but when I implement it to write all of my array to the file it crashes. Here's my code:

```
void writeFile(void)
{
  char *fileName[30];
  cout << "enter a filename";
  cin >> *fileName;
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open (*fileName);
  int p;

  for(p = 0; p <= i; p++)
    {
      myfile << right << setw(4) << setfill('0') << packet[i].getSource() <<  ":";
      myfile << right << setw(4) << setfill('0') << packet[i].getDest() <<  ":";
      myfile << right << setw(4) << setfill('0') << packet[i].getType() <<  ":";
      myfile << right << setw(4) << setfill('0') << packet[i].getPort() <<  endl;
    }
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What is i?  It doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.

Comment: it looks like when you reference `packet[i]` you maybe meant `packet[p]`

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant Bob, thanks for the heads up, still shouldnt make it crash though?
And sorry, i is global, init at 0.

Comment: `char *fileName[30];` is a double pointer. Why?

Comment: @Tibor:  No, that is not a double pointer.  It is an array of pointer.  Its use is questionable, of course, and `std::string fileName; if (!std::getline(std::cin, fileName)) throw std::runtime_error("Read failed");` would be preferable (one needs not necessarily throw an exception, but one should note the potential for error and handle the situation accordingly).

Comment: @Tibor: no, it is not. It's an array of pointers.

Answer (score 3):

`fileName` is an array of 30 uninitialized pointers to char. `*fileName` is the same as `filename[0]`, which is an uninitialized pointer to a char. You cannot use this pointer for anything but assigning it a valid value. You are not doing that, though, and instead you're trying to read data to it, with predictably catastrophic consequences.

In short, you shouldn't be using any pointers in C++ at all, and instead use an `std::string` for your situation:

```
std::string fileName;
if (!(std::cin >> fileName)) { /* I/O error, die */ }
// ...
```

(Perhaps what you meant to do is to make `fileName` an array of 30 chars: `char fileName[30];`. But don't do that. Even though it might work, it's very terrible.)

Comment: +1 for the classic 'didn't malloc any space for string but cinned it in anyway'

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've changed to a string and dropped the pointers, but I'm getting an error:

error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::string&)'|

Comment: In the old C++, there was no constructor for an `ofstream` from a `string`. This has been fixed in C++11, but in the meantime, say `std::ofstream f(fileName.c_str());`. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

There is another thing slightly dodgy here:

```
for(p = 0; p <= i; p++)
```

you probably want

```
for(p = 0; p < i; p++)
```

so that you don't try to dereference off the end of your array

probably better to write

```
for (int p = 0; p != i; ++p)
```

This is the recommended form according to Moo and Koenig: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184402072

I would also not use `char *` to read from a `cin`, use `std::string` to store your string and inputs, you do not need to `new` the memory if it is not needed outside the scope of your main `writeFile` function. Strings support dynamic resizing also so you don't need to initialise it to any size, here is the first example I googled to help you [understand](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0300__string/Usecintoreadstring.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the "C way" to store your file name? And you're using it the wrong way: char**. It would be easier to just declare:

```
std::string fileName;
while(!std::cin >> fileName);
ofstream myfile(fileName.c_str());
```

You also are using i inside of your loop but are iterating over p, I think that's not what you want to do ...